# Take output field data string into variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, string

I want to grep for some specific lines from a log file, and then capture a specific part of that output in a variable and use it in other commands.

The grep command I have is the following, where $1 is a date:

```
grep -a --binary-file=text "pattern" /home/path/archive/logs/path.log-$1
```

Example output:

```
/home/path/archive/logs/path.log-2015-04-13.0.gz:2015-05-13 00:43:49,779 INFO [DEUX-DR-SAMPLE-1] c.i.s.p.DeuxProxyPMMProcessor [DEUX : 361] SVRREQ|dataID|server request: (deliver: (pdu: 0 5 0 282190) (addr: 1 1 adress)  (addr: 1 1 mssidn)  (sm: enc: ASCII msg: id:dataID stat:pattern)
```

From this output I want to take only the `dataID` field and save it in a variable for use in other commands. There are hundreds of lines like this though, and the number of spaces can't be used as a delimiter to get the `dataID` field because it varies from line to line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` with PCRE:

```
$ var='/home/path/archive/logs/path.log-2015-04-13.0.gz:2015-05-13 00:43:49,779 INFO [DEUX-DR-SAMPLE-1] c.i.s.p.DeuxProxyPMMProcessor [DEUX : 361] SVRREQ|dataID|server request: (deliver: (pdu: 0 5 0 282190) (addr: 1 1 adress)  (addr: 1 1 mssidn)  (sm: enc: ASCII msg: id:dataID stat:pattern)'

$ grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' <<<"$var"
dataID
```

To save it in a variable:

```
$ foobar="$(grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' <<<"$var")"
```

Comment: what is this line for grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' <<<"$var"

Comment: @Asif I have saved the line you have provided as a variable named `var`, i thought it would be easier to understand..in case of a file if you use e.g. `for line in file` or `while read line`, then you can use `foobar="$(grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' <<<"$line")"`

Comment: @Asif If you are not clear enough please let me know (and with a precise question)..

Comment: ok, so if i want to run another command in the same script file eg:    grep $var /path/to/another/file.log.. does it return an output line-by-line based on output in variable (    var    )?

Comment: @Asif: If you have multiple files like the one you provided in a file e.f. `file.txt`, then running `grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' file.txt` will give you all `dataID` found in the file..you should not use the variable in this case, you can use an array instead to save all the outputs e.g. `foobar=( "$(grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' file.txt )`......on the other hand if you are reading file line by line then use `foobar="$(grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' <<<"$line")"`, where $line` represents each line..

Comment: actually im using the statement like this : `zgrep -a --binary-file=text "REJECTD" /home/gemp/archive/logs/gemp.log-$1* | grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)'` in 1 of my script function and return `dataID` (more than 1 line) output. From this I want to run another another function using the output from previous statement ,next function still `grep` but from another file. do i use the same method using `var` as variable?

Comment: If i understand correctly, then only one match of `dataID` in `/home/gemp/archive/logs/gemp.log-$1*` would do, right?

Comment: what do mean by one match?

Comment: If any line contains `dataID`, you are good?

Comment: actually that is solved `zgrep -a --binary-file=text "REJECTD" /home/gemp/archive/logs/gemp.log-$1* | grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)'` already return what i want , the problem is by the return result how do i convert it into variable and use it in another function?

Comment: , let say `zgrep -a --binary-file=text "REJECTD" /home/gemp/archive/logs/gemp.log-$1* | grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' <<< "$line"`. does `$line` will store the variable as array? because i want to run another `grep` in another function that must return same count as `dataID` (eg: dataID return `aaa`,`bbb`,`ccc` the next command will return `string aaa`,`string bbb`,`string ccc`).tell me if anything is unclear.im not very good at explaining :P

Comment: Well, then `foobar="$(zgrep -a --binary-file=text "REJECTD" /home/gemp/archive/logs/gemp.log-$1* | grep -m 1 -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' <<< "$line")"` will stop after first match as all the matches will be `dataID`, there is no point in creating an array out from them..`$foobar` will have `dataID`..next run grep -c "$goobar" another_file.txt` ..it will give you the number of occurrences of `dataID` in `another_file.txt`..

Comment: can I ask what grep `-m 1` means?

Comment: `grep -m 1` means `grep` will stop after finding the first match..check `man grep`

Comment: ive tried to do like u mention `rejected_message_today () {

 foobar="$(grep -a --binary-file=text "REJECTD" /home/gemp/gemp/logs/gemp.log-$1* | grep -Po '.*?SVRREQ\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' << "$line")"
 
 grep -c $foobar /home/gemp/gemp/data/sdr/processed/cdr.log-$1*

}` and return below result ./findRejectedMsg.sh: line 6: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `$line')
./findRejectedMsg.sh: line 6: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `$line')``
`

Comment: Thats not what i suggested, anyway what are you wanting now is just another thing, not what the question was initially about.....please ask it as a new question (you can use the reference to this question if you want)..also if this answer solved your initial query please mark it as accepted by clicking the left sided tick mark of this answer..